# How could i get over NoReverseMatch at /polls/reset-password/ error to continue in making password resetting?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

My urls.py is this and even though i have created the password-reset-done url

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout, password_reset, 
password_reset_done, password_reset_confirm, password_reset_complete

urlpatterns= [
    url(r'^$',views.index, name= "index"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name= "detail"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls/1
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results$', views.results, name="results"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls/1/results
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote$', views.vote, name="vote"),
    #127.0.0.1/polls/1/vote
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'polls/login.html'}),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'template_name': 'polls/logout.html'}),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name= 'register'),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name= 'profile'),
    url(r'^edit_profile/$', views.edit_profile, name= 'edit_profile'),
    url(r'^change-password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
    url(r'^reset-password/$', password_reset, name='reset_password'),
    url(r'^reset-password/done/$', password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
]
```

I am getting the following error.

[image: Error image]

Comment: you might be missing `namespace`. try like `reverse('polls:password_reset_done')`. Replace `polls` with your namespace if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have included the password reset urls inside the `polls` app. That means that you would reverse the URL with `'polls:password_reset_done'` instead of `'password_reset_done'`.

Since you don't want to have to edit Django's password reset views, The easiest fix would be to move the password reset URLs out of `polls/urls.py` and into your main `urls.py` (the one in the same directory as `settings.py`)

Comment: "it is not working yet" isn't enough information to know what the problem is. We don't know what your code is now, or what message you are seeing.

Comment: I am referring to video 21 of  django tutorial for how to generate password reset email....and i am getting the syntax error after putting polls: password_reset_done

Comment: As I said, I think putting `polls:password_reset_done` is probably the wrong approach. I would move the password reset URLs out of `polls/urls.py` instead.

Comment: should i also move password_reset?

Comment: Yes, I would move all of the password reset URLs.